# call key from a previous raw_input

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

I am creating a program in Python, to better learn the language.

As of right now I have two empty dictionaries, one named `bankAccount` and `pinCode`.
`bankAccount` gets it's key and value from raw_input and input, but for `pinCode`, I want to take the raw_input from the `bankAccount` dictionary and use that as a key for the PIN in `pinCode` dictionary. How can I do that?

I want the code to be universal, so if another person enters information the same thing happens for them, so I can't use `d[dictkey]`.

```
bankAccount = {} 
pinCode = {} 
bankAccount[raw_input("And what is your name?")] = input("Hello and welcome to MyBank, can I take your bank account number, please?") 
pinCode[] = input("Can we have your PIN code, please?")
```

Comment: This is going to be very hard to answer without more information about your code. Can you edit the question with the relevant bits? Especially, we need to see the code from creating the `bankAccount` and `pinCode` dicts, and how you want to be accessing them. I suspect you just need to use a variable to hold the `raw_input` value, but I'm not sure I've understood the issue correctly.

Comment: `bankAccount = {}
pinCode = {}

bankAccount[raw_input("And what is your name?")] = input("Hello and welcome to MyBank, can I take your bank account number, please?")

pinCode[] = input("Can we have your PIN code, please?")`

The pinCode[dictkey], the dictkey is going to take it's key, from the raw_input in backAccount.

Comment: I added your code to the post - please adjust if I interpreted it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting input from the user that you need to use more than once (as a key for both of your dictionaries), you'll need to save the value in a variable. It might not be a bad idea to do this for the other input values too, but that's not strictly required. Something like this will work:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
acct = input("What is your account number?")
pin = input("What is your PIN?")

bankAccount[name] = acct
pinCode[name] = pin
```

I'm not sure what you mean by your final paragraph about the code being universal. You'll need to clarify that part if you still need help with it.